# How to get element | value from list object in django (jinja) in the html? I know how get first value, but how about second, third

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm a new in the world of django! Please help me!
I can get all values in the list, but I need exactly, for example third value or element in the list? How to filter it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by

```
{{ mylist.2 }} for 3rd value
```

See [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)